# How can I detect if my code is running in the console in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in an initializer:

```
if $0 == 'irb'
  # ...
end
```

It works fine with Rails 2.3 but in Rails 3 the value of $0 is 'script/rails' no matter if it was started with rails c or rails s. ARGV is an empty array. How can I detect if the application has been started with "rails c" or "rails console"?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could try this perhaps

```
if defined?(Rails::Console)
  # in Rails Console
else
  # Not in Rails Console
end
```

Comment: Note that this won't work during Rails initialization when running Spring.

Comment: You want `Rails.const_defined?("Console")`, not `defined?(Rails::Console)`.

Comment: @wxgeorge why is that better?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman `Rails::Console` is not defined in all contexts and configurations. When it's not, you'll get a `NameError`. `Rails.const_defined?("Console")` is safe so long as `Rails` is defined.

Comment: @wxgeorge @Andreas `defined?` is a special method and will let you pass whatever name you want, e.g. `defined?(Hwddddw::Ewedw) # => nil`

Comment: @Dorian - whoa my bad! Apologies. I got an error when I first used Aditya's original formulation, and assumed it was as I reported above. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: unless i'm missing something, this is not working anymore in rails 6. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57526113/293974 *is* working.

Answer (score 8):

Many years later there is a better method to do this registering blocks to run for the console (using the [railtie](https://devdocs.io/rails/rails/railtie) interface).

So in the initializer you can write:

```rb
Rails.application.console do
  # your code here
end
```

The good think about this is that it also works for `runner` and it should also work with spring (but I didn't test that).

Comment: works for me in rails 6, unlike ` defined?(Rails::Console)`

Comment: Works in initialization with spring. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there something related to this solution that facilitates conditionally doing something in `config.after_initialize` only when *not* using a console? That's my use case.

Comment: @WillHaslett `defined?(Rails::Console)` works for me in this context.

Comment: @WillHaslett had asked -- "is there a way to do this when _not_ using a console?" and another option if you just want to run stuff only when it's a **rails s** then put your code in **config.ru**.

Comment: Works for me in rails 7